# What are the process for a custom chain to be officially supported and listed on the website?

Tags: gnosis-safe

What steps or criteria must be met for a custom chain to be officially supported and included on the [Safe web app](https://app.safe.global/)? In other words, how can one see their custom chain listed alongside other supported networks like Polygon, Arbitrum, Volta, and Goerli?

The official Safe documentation at https://help.safe.global/en/articles/6227806-supported-networks states:

> The Safe team does not have the capacity to spin up and maintain full frontend and backend support for all EVM-based networks. All Safe related source code is open source. We encourage everyone to deploy the canonical versions of the Safe contracts to their respective networks and run the required backend and frontend parts themselves.

However, there is no information on how to get a custom chain listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The Safe team does not have the capacity to spin up and maintain full frontend and backend support for all EVM-based networks."

This means the team doesn't have the technical resources to maintain new
networks. They do not list networks maintained by 3rd parties.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this but I think you need to contact the developers of the Safe web app and up next you will need to provide documentation for your custom chain, including its technical specifications and any other relevant information